# Why 'dd' command with differernt bs (blocks size) doesn't affect bi_size?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to test a block device driver.

When I use 'dd' command with different bs block sizes, the bi_size field in the 'bio' structure doesn't seem to change. It remains at 4KB.

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, I'm running 'dd' outputting directly to my device (of=/dev/xxx) and not going through VFS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 4KB is a sector size of your block device, so all requests to it are aligned on that value.

From [LDD3, Chapter 16](https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch16.pdf)

> Once that is done, the kernel adheres to your device’s hardware sector size. All I/O requests are properly aligned at the beginning of a hardware sector, and the length of each request is an integral number of sectors.

Note, that by using `dd` on block device files (of=/dev/xxx), you **actually go through VFS**. Interface of block device differs from one of files, so operations(e.g. read/write) on the file, representing block device, are wrappers around block device operations. (Moreover, *any* access on *any* file goes through VFS.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I agree with your pointing out that it still goes through VFS. I believe bi_size is the number of sectors for the request. I expected it to be more than just 1. I just see many bio requests, all sequential and with bi_size of 1 block of 4KB. If I fdisk and mount the device, then do 'dd' to a file at the mount point, then I see the bi_size matches the bs parameter. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The block size of `dd` is just the block size used when `dd` is reading and writing to the files. The kernel is not required to write to a device using the same block size (or at the same time) as the user-space process which is requesting a write of that size. The kernel has buffering for VFS operations (and also maintains some guarantees that a certain block size write will be atomic, which is 4KB IIRC). And by the way, the `/dev/` block devices do go through VFS (the fact that the block size isn't controlled by you should be evidence enough of that).

So yeah, the `bs` option in `dd` doesn't affect the block size the kernel uses when actually serialising writes to a device.

Comment: Thank you for giving additional insight. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can try to control the bi_size that VFS is issuing to my device driver? I would prefer it to be much bigger than 4K. I've experimented with the values in /sys/block/<dev>/queue, and that has some effects, but only if I go through mkfs. I'm learning to write a block device driver, and would like to have control for testing. I would like to test for specific bi_sizes, and not just let the filesystem all kinds of sizes  to me. Thanks again for your reply!